# Amazon DynamoDB vs relational database

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I want to store huge amount of trading data (say million records per day) using some kind of data base. Each record is small and has static structure: id(integer), time stamp(integer), price(float), size (float). Id field is primary key here (in terms of relational data bases). And I want to select records from specific time range (ordered by time). These is straightforward in a relational database.

Is nosql data base (DynamoDB in particular) suitable for these requirements? Or should I use traditional relational database solution ?

I don't have any experience with NoSql data bases.

Comment: Whenever you feel that you should ask a question with "vs" in the title, you might want to read [gorilla vs. shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward answer to this question is yes, this fits DynamoDB's use case well. But there's a better answer: **try it out and see!**

I have been seeing a lot of this kind of question regarding AWS, namely "will this work?" as opposed to "how do I do this?" And the best way to answer that is to try it out and see. Unlike traditional IT, you don't have to do a lot of planning or invest a lot of capital up front to try it out. Spend a buck or two (literally that little) to run a little test program using DynamoDB and another using MySQL (or other RDBMS) and see how they work for you.

Comment: "this fits DynamoDB's use case well" unless of course there's an unstated need to easily do things like COUNT(), SUM(), AVG(), MIN(), MAX()... :) still, +1 for "try it out and see" because that's going to answer the question better than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamodb would work, however given that each record is small, static structure in my opinion, a relational database would be equally well suited for this task, perhaps even better (which is very subjective).

Don't forget to calculate the costs of both solutions; you can easily install mysql (free) or sql server (not free once you get past a certain point) on an ec2 instance and you will know exactly what your monthly costs will be.

Dynamodb is priced very differently, so you really need to quantify your reads/writes and storage requirements in order to know what you are in for. Best to figure these things out ahead of time unless money is not a concern.